# Invitation to contribute to an answer

Tags: discussion

The question **[Did the science of mathematics begin with the Vedas?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2673/36)**
has a beautiful answer by a user. I strongly think this is really a great question. But it can be made more beautiful if the professionals around here on this site do contribute to make it more better.

Here is the link to the [answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2710/93).

Also invite other professionals who are not on this site.

Please try maximum to keep the relevant source links.

Comment: Well, I just posted a comment casting doubt on that answer.  I don't think that's what you wanted. ;-)

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan tbh, I just need a correct detailed answer. thanks for responding :)